# booting to frozen virtual console after `prime-select intel`

Tags: boot, drivers, xorg, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-prime

I've got a Dell inspiron 15 7559 laptop with a nVidia GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] graphical card. After getting it to boot correctly and installing the nvidia drivers using the additional drivers tab (nvidia-352) I was able to boot perfectly normal.

When I switched to the intel card using `prime-select intel` and logged out I couldn't log back in. I was able to use a virtual console to revert back to nvidia and log back in. So I thought perhaps it needs a reboot for the changes. After the reboot I booted into a frozen virtual console. I had to go to recovery mode and execute `prime-select nvidia` in a console to be able to boot normally again.

My guess is that something with the intel drivers is broken and crashes xorg.

I've also tried bumblebee with the same results. It booted into a frozen VC and only worked after everything was run using Nvidia again.
Anyone got any suggestions??

edit: I think gpu-manager is writing using the nvidia driver. I am currently trying to find a way to get gpu-manager to work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you should use the drivers from the official Ubuntu repositories. But when there are problems with the drivers ... you can install the more current drivers from the GPU Drivers PPA.

Uninstall the currently installed NVIDIA drivers and bumblebee - remove the xorg-edgers PPA.

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and the password, then execute :
Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia* bumblebee
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo reboot
```

Now install the latest official NVIDIA drivers 361 that support the NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 960M.

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and the password, then execute :
Open a terminal and execute :

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```